# can you copy autopilot bot

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Can you copy an existing autopilot programable message bot you made and then rename it and assign a different number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do that with the [Autopilot CLI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/twilio-autopilot-cli)!

[Here are the commands you can use, like export](https://github.com/dabblelab/twilio-cli-autopilot-plugin): you can export your bot as a schema file and then import it as a schema file. You can also use some [templates here](https://github.com/twilio/autopilot-templates)

Let me know if this helps at all!